# Change Bibliography to References in Latex using Overleaf template

Tags: latex, overleaf

I am using a Latex template for Thesis. The template is available on https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/curtin-university-phd-thesis-template-for-astronomy/ggxgtpqnydcx

I am not a Latex expert to understand the details, I am able to just use it.

The list of references comes with a heading "Bibliography" when compiled to pdf, but I want it as "References". I am not sure how to change this, any suggestions will be greatly helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the else parton the .cls file as below :

```
\if@APA
\RequirePackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\fi
\if@Vancouver
    \RequirePackage[numbers]{natbib}
    \bibliographystyle{unsrtnat}
\else
    \RequirePackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
    \if@Chicago
        \bibliographystyle{chicago}
    \fi
    \if@Harvard
        \bibliographystyle{harvard}
    \fi
\fi
```